# Iterate through an entire table with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape all of the player names and fantasy info on the players listed on this [site](http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/adp/overall.php).  I can find the table absolutely fine, but the trouble starts when I try and iterate over the entire table.  Here's the code I've written so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

nfl = 'http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/adp/overall.php'
html = urlopen(nfl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")

table = soup.find('tbody').find_next('tbody')

playername = table.find('td').find_next('td')
for row in table:
    print(playername)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Adrian Peterson MIN, 5
Le'Veon Bell PIT, 11
```

and so on and so forth for the rest of the players on the chart.

**Actual output**:

```
Adrian Peterson MIN, 5 
Adrian Peterson MIN, 5 
Adrian Peterson MIN, 5
```

and so on for over 400 iterations.

Where is my `for` loop going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the search in the context of a particular table:

```
for row in table:
    print(row.find('td').find_next('td'))
```

Though, I would approach the problem differently. The desired table has an `id`:

```
table = soup.find('table', id="data")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:  # skipping header row
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    print(cells[0].text, cells[1].find('a').text)
```

Prints:

```
(u'1', u'Adrian Peterson')
(u'2', u"Le'Veon Bell")
(u'3', u'Eddie Lacy')
(u'4', u'Jamaal Charles')
(u'5', u'Marshawn Lynch')
...
```